# Missing dependency for FormDataParam with jersey-multipart-1.18.1

Tags: java, maven, jersey, multipart

I had this horrible problem with the file uploads through the Jersey REST (with Dropwizard, but that doesn't matter that much).
The error didn't appear when we tested and run it with Eclipse, but when we deployed it with the jars, this came up, no matter what we changed (except for removing the upload method at all)

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.zh.backend.rest.resources.FileManagerResource.uploadFile(com.zh.backend.beans.User,java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.zh.backend.rest.resources.FileManagerResource.uploadFile(com.zh.backend.beans.User,java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.zh.backend.rest.resources.FileManagerResource.uploadFile(com.zh.backend.beans.User,java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 2
```

So then we found this topic https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2010-09/message/267 which said just enough to know where to search for the problem - the merging of the jersey-core and jersey-multipart didn't merge the META-INF/services files, it rather overwrote one with the other.

If you want to fix the problem, merge the same name files from META-INF/services from jersey-core and jersey-multipart manually into your jar's META-INF/services and if you happen to have your own injection providers, specify them in their own files in META-INF/services (you might have to create those files). I had to edit manually the jar that was generated from Maven, but you can figure the automated process with the Maven Shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Maven fix that will make everything OK and automatic

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                      <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```